# Lines over 9-patch images

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have 9-patched image (button with rounded corners and incon in the middle) with non gradient (gradient is on the background - lower layer, not button itself) alpha-channeled content, in draw 9-path it looks like this:

[image: 9-path shot]

I have resources only for hdpi, so my assumption is that it scales for other densities. Now, in some cases horizontal line (or lines) appear, like on following shots:

[image: Line 1]
[image: Line 2]

I thought its due to scaling, but in some non-hdpi densities is button viewed correctly. I also find [another thread at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792873/transparent-9patch-image-line-showing-through), but in that case it looks like its happening due to gradient I think.

How can I get rid of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced some unexpected behavior on 9Patch when using odd numbers in the 9patch (keep in mind that if your xhdpi 9patch is 75px high it'll be 37,5px in mdpi and that might lead to unexpected drawing scenarios).

My advice is to make your graphics as consistent as possible with resolutions (l(3), m(4), h(6) and xh(8)) as well as geometrically balanced (ie.: your resizable area at the top is bigger than at the bottom, do you really need that?).

Will be waiting for your answer back!

Comment: Thanks for reply, Jose. I tried to use only one pixel wide patches and also (as you recommend) the same pixel count on both sides, but without success - lines are still there. I'm testing only on hdpi now and my 9-patched image is 182x82. Or do you mean that image size on hdpi should be multiple of 6?

Comment: Hey Shmoula!
You are using hdpi graphics and testing in a hdpi device? 
I'm curious now, if you share the image I'll try it here and give it a look.

Comment: You are very welcome! I use enclosed image as a hdpi source on hdpi device emulator: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/729838/button_synchro_pressed.9.png

Comment: Yep, the button is fine, and it's pretty unlikely that the background origins that, it has something to do with the 9patch compilation process. Is there any other characteristic that might explain that behavior (pre / post ICS?). Does it happen with in other densities?
I tried on a hdpi emulator and a xhdpi device and working perfectly. Did you "Refresh + clean projet"'ed before trying again?

Comment: Yes, I refreshed and cleaned project many times. I'm testing it on 4.1.2 (api 16) and 2.3.3 (api 10) and with only hdpi resources just now. Did you replicate the 'line' bug on your side?

Comment: Not at all. Works fine for me in all cases. So you are facing that issue in both environments.? I've just tried with 4.1.2 hdpi and still works fine. 
Did you try putting a different background (ie.: plain black) to see if that has something to do with the issue?

Comment: Oh my! That's good news :). It really works outside that bar, just as ImageButton. And now I can see that - bar height is 45dp and when I apply this height to working image, lines appear! So I'm going to update image source to corresponding height and use even numbers only!

Comment: That did the trick! I moved my 9-patched resources to xhdpi folder and now lower densities works correctly too! Thank you for your time, marking as solved!

Comment: Nice! Good news shmoula. Yeah it looked like all was fine with the button. It was a pleasure! Happy coding.